# Integral of a matrix exponent

Tags: integration, matrices, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, matrix-calculus

What is the analytic closed form  expression  of

$\int e^{A_1+A_2s} \ ds  \tag 1$

where A and B are constant skew symmetric matrices

**NB**

1. $A_1=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
      0 & -c_0 & b_0 \\
      c_0 & 0 & -a_0 \\
     -b_0 & a_0 & 0 \\
      \end{array} \right) \tag  2$
2. $A_2=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
      0 & -c_1 & b_1 \\
      c_1 & 0 & -a_1 \\
     -b_1 & a_1 & 0 \\
      \end{array} \right) \tag  3$  All $a_i,b_i,c_i$ ($i= 0,1$) are constants. Only s is the variable
3. $A_1+A_2s$ and $ (A_1+A_2s)^{'} $ (derivative) are not commutative
4. I tried to use expression for matrix exponent in skew symmetric matrices using the formula  shown below

   [image]

Please click [here](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/papers/gallier/rodrig.pdf)(page 1 right bottom in the pdf  link) for reference source  . But the issue is this form is very tough to integrate